I want to verify the logo through link
I need my code to switch from frame 4 to frame 5, click on the link, and verify whether the logo is present.
My code is able to switch from frame 4 to 5 and click on the link but is not able to verify the logo.
// frame4
WebElement frame4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@src='frame_4.html']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame4);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mytext4']")).sendKeys("Assignment");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    
// switch to frame5
WebElement frame5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@src='frame_5.html']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame5);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mytext5']")).sendKeys("frames");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/a")).click();
boolean b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='UI Vision by a9t9 software - Image-Driven Automation']")).isDisplayed();
if(b)
{
    System.out.println("Present");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("not ");
}


The method .isDisplayed() is intended to check if an already existing element is visible or not. My guess is that sometimes the image does not exist or your locator is not correct and the code throws when you try to find the element. First you need to make sure the element exists and then check to see if it's visible. To do this you can use the pattern,
List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(...);
if (e.isEmpty()) {
    // element does not exist
} else {
    // element does exist
}


Some feedback...

I added some WebDriverWaits to your code. You should use them when the element you are looking for isn't always immediately available. It will make your script perform more consistently.

With the waits I added, I used ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(). This waits for the IFRAME to exist and then switches to it.

If .isDisplayed() returns true, that means that the element is visible, not "Present" as you are printing to the console. Present in Selenium terms means that the element exists in the DOM, not that it's visible. I corrected this in your print statement.

I simplified your print statement by printing the resulting Boolean rather than using an if statement to print different strings.



Incorporating the above pattern and feedback into your code,
// frame4
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@src='frame_4.html']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mytext4']")).sendKeys("Assignment");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    
// switch to frame5
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@src='frame_5.html']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='mytext5']")).sendKeys("frames");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/a")).click();
List<WebElement> image = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt='UI Vision by a9t9 software - Image-Driven Automation']"));
Boolean visible = !image.isEmpty() && image.get(0).isDisplayed();
System.out.println("Visible: " + visible);

